# Routing error in rendering partial form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, partial

I'm making a project for which I have a class `online_score` which has as one of its attributes an array called `url` of `online_score_url` objects. What I did up to now is the following. The code might be a little dirty because I'm constantly trying new things, but as soon as I get it working, I'll clean it up.
views/online_score/new:

```
<h3>Links: </h3>
<div class="urlInput">
<%f.fields_for :url do |f| %>
<div class="inputset">
<%= f.label :url %>  <%= f.url_field :url, :value => "http://www.google.be"%>
<%= f.label :description %>  <%= f.text_field :description %>
<%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", f %>
</div>
<%end %>
<%= add_url_link "Add Another link", f %> #works fine if I remove this rule
</div>
```

views/online_score/_online_score_url_fields:

```
<%= f.fields_for :item do |b| %>
<div class="inputset">
<%= b.label :url %>  <%= b.url_field :url, :value => "http://www.google.be"%>
<%= b.label :description %>  <%#= b.text_field :description %>
<%= link_to_remove_fields "remove", b %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

My problem is now that I want to be able to dynamically add inputs for `online_score_url`objects which I try to do with JQuery. I try to do this by rendering the partial like so:
helpers/online_scores_helper.rb:

```
def add_url_link(name, f)
link_to_function name do |page|    
  item = OnlineScoreUrl.new("", "")
  instrument_online_score = render :partial => "online_score_url_fields", :locals => {:f => f, :item => item}

  page << %{
    $('.links').append("#{ escape_javascript online_score_url }");
  }
end
end
```

The problem now is that it gives the following error:

> ActionController::RoutingError in Online_scores#new
>
> Showing /home/kvhooreb/jenna_vopro/score/app/views/online_scores/new.html.erb where line >#22 raised:
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"online_scores", :locale=>:en}
>   Extracted source (around line #22):
>
> 19:   
>   20:     <%#= render "online_score_url_fields", :f => f %>
>   21:   <%end %>
>   22:   <%= add_url_link "Add Another link", f %>
>   23:   
>   24:
>   25:   
>   Rails.root: /home/kvhooreb/jenna_vopro/score
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/helpers/online_scores_helper.rb:20:in `block in add_url_link'
>   app/helpers/online_scores_helper.rb:15:in`add_url_link'
>   app/views/online_scores/new.html.erb:22:in `block in >_app_views_online_scores_new_html_erb__1492671958001855269_22836400_2958786211230549542'
>   app/views/online_scores/new.html.erb:3:in >`_app_views_online_scores_new_html_erb__1492671958001855269_22836400_2958786211230549542'
>   Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"piece"=>"1",
>   "locale"=>"en"}

Now I have no clue what causes this. Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which line is line 15 of app/helpers/online_scores_helper.rb ?  I am betting that it's the one with "escape_javascript online_score_url"

Comment: What does your route definition look like for your online_scores resource?  Have you defined it in routes.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off the information you've provided, I am going to assume the problem is in `app/helpers/online_scores_helper.rb`, specifically, this line:

```
$('.links').append("#{ escape_javascript online_score_url }");
```

If you've defined a standard resource for online_scores, you either are referring to a specific online score record `online_score_url(online_score.id)`, or referring to the list of online scores `online_score_urls`.

`online_score_url`, being singular, normally would expect an `id` in order to render the route.  Without it, you would get the error message:

```
"No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"online_scores", :locale=>:en} Extracted source (around line #22):"
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. Your comment wast the solution, but It made mee see my mistake. `online_score_url` is a variable which should be defined here: `instrument_online_score = render :partial => "online_score_url_fields", :locals => {:f => f, :item => item}` so that should be: `online_score_url = render :partial => "online_score_url_fields", :locals => {:f => f, :item => item}`. I copy pasted some code apparently and I forgot to edit that. It doesn't work completely yet, but at least it doesn't give an error anymore so I can start looking into that again. thanks.